# Wi-Fi stops working after suspending the machine

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, suspend

Well I normally don't ask for help on this type of forums, but I really need help

So yesterday I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and everything was going well, but after I suspended my machine and came back the Wi-Fi stopped working.

And I don't know if this is a common issue, so I came up with a solution that kinda fix the problem and it's basically preventing the computer from suspending itself.

But of course I really want a real solution for this problem, so if anybody knows a solution for this problem I'll appreciate your support :)

Comment: Welcome. You didn't say which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product you're asking about (*they have different defaults & those defaults influenced by media used to install*). I assume Desktop (not Server, *flavor* etc), but it's best if you are specific rather than having us guess. I've experienced the issue 2-3 times and I would just restart networking to resolve it after waking system, but that's only a work-around. Which 22.04 product? which 22.04 kernel stack?  (22.04 Desktop defaults to HWE)...  Also this is a Q&A site & not a forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums)

Comment: .. so if you provide additional details (eg. you're using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, not Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server etc) please add them to your question via edit...  You don't respond via comment to me; my comment(s) will get removed once addressed in the question, as its your question itself that people will answer  (*they can elect to ignore comments - this isn't a forum which can require reading long threads*)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** As @guiverc has already pointed out, more information is needed here. I'd also ask that you please add additional information about your machine (make/model and model year if applicable) as this information will help others in the future who may end up running into the same issue you're currently experiencing. Thanks

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting